# NET Core The SSL connection could not be established - .HTTPClient

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, ssl, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to hit a REST call in a .net core 3.1 application. While making the rest call, I receive the error 'The SSL Connection could not be established'. I'd like to bypass it. I've used the following code to bypass the SSL certificate but it doesn't work.

```
 using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
        {

            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (request, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authorization);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/xml");


                var response = httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(url)).Result;


                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string result = string.Empty;
                await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith((Task<string> x) =>
                {
                    if (x.IsFaulted)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {x.Exception.StackTrace}");
                        throw x.Exception;
                    }

                    result = x.Result;
                });

                return result;
            }
        }
```

I would really appreciate a solution to bypass the SSL certificate in the .net core application so I can make the REST call successfully.

Comment: Could you please share the details inner exception for the `'The SSL Connection could not be established'` error? It seems not all the exception could be by passed.

Comment: To add to the last comment: only problems which are triggered by the local machine can be fixed or worked around on the local machine, like missing trust in the servers certificate. If instead the server decides that it will not accept the client then this cannot be bypassed on the local machine. It is unclear what happens in your case since there are no sufficient details about the error.